# Issue when passing Data through segue in swift

Tags: ios, swift, null, segue

I know this question has already been answered but that does not solve my issue. The issue is when I am passing data through segue it returns nil in destination ViewController.
Let say I have defined a News() object and three string object in destination ViewController Which I am setting in Segue method but got nil in destination ViewController.

```
class NewsDetailViewController: UIViewController {
    var objNews = News();
    var newsTime: String?
    var newsDetail: String?
    var imageURL: String?

// rest of the class
.
.
}
```

and here is my segue method

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if segue.identifier == "SegueNewsDetail" {
        var ndVC = NewsDetailViewController();
        var indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tblViewStudent.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
        var tempObj = self.news.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as News
        ndVC.objNews = (self.news.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as News)
        ndVC.newsTime = tempObj.created_at;
        ndVC.newsDetail = tempObj.newsDescription;
        ndVC.imageURL = tempObj.imageURL;

        println("\(ndVC.newsTime) \(ndVC.newsDetail) \(ndVC.imageURL)")

    }
```

when I try to log the values in segue method to check if values are setting or not (These value are setting with desired values, I mean don't get nil here in segue method):

```
println("\(ndVC.newsTime) \(ndVC.newsDetail) \(ndVC.imageURL)")
```

I tried many option but failed.
Anyone please help..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

change

```
var ndVC = NewsDetailViewController()
```

to

```
let ndVC = segue.destinationViewController as! NewsDetailViewController
```

btw you don't need semicolon in swift

Comment: I do but now i got the error "Expected type after as" .
@miracle-doh

Comment: are you using xcode 6.2?If so, just try `as` instead of `as!`  because Xcode 6.3 requires as the exclamation mark to unwrap the optional

Comment: Great! Can you check accept answer button, appreciate it!